# How to pass values into the constructor of the base class without the constructor of the child class in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

In C++, I created a base class called parent. In this class, I create a constructor that can take one parameter. My sub-class name is child. There haven't any constructor in my child class. My code is given below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class parent{
public:
    parent(int number){
        cout<<"Value of the number from parent class is: "<<number<<endl;
    }
};
class child: public parent{
public:
    child(): parent(10){
    }
};
int main()
{
    child ob(100);
    return 0;
}
```

When I am trying to run the above code, compiler "shows no matching function for call to 'child::child(int)'".

I don't want to create any parameterized constructor in the child class. How can I pass the value of the constructor of the parent class? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Add a using declaration `using parent::parent;` in the child class.

Comment: How is this related to multiple-inheritance, and specifically to c++17 ? Please remove unrelated tags.

Comment: Just curious, which problem would you like to solve by not adding a child's c'tor?

Answer (score 5):

You have three alternatives:

1. Don't use parameters, only use `child` default construction
2. Create a `child` constructor taking the arguments that's needed (possibly with a default value)
3. Pull in the `parent` constructor into the `child` class:

   ```
   class child : public parent {
   public:
       using parent::parent;  // Add the parent constructor to this scope

       child() : parent(10) {
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: Note that `using parent::parent;` is just a shortcut for typing #2. This creates more `child` constructors that are copies of each `parent` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve this problem?

Add a using declaration `using parent::parent;` in the child class.

```
class child: public parent{
public:
    using parent::parent; //added this using declaration
    child(): parent(10){
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `main` Method you try to call a constructor from the `child` class with an `int` as parameter. This error originates from the absence of this constructor. To pass `number` to the parent class you would need a constructor like:

```cpp
child(int number): parent(number) {}
```

in your `child` class.

Comment: I don't want to create any constructor in the child class. By the way, I got the answer from the above solution.

Comment: `using parent::parent` is identical to creating constructors in the child class.

Comment: @MooingDuck it somehow is, but firstly, it pulls up all other c'tors a well. And secondly it does less code duplication, with the benefit, that when you refactor the base class' c'tor you don't have to change any derived one. See the *Inheriting constructors* section in the [C++ Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this type of problem in single inheritance is given in the first comment. But in case of multi level inheritance we can solve by the following way:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class parent{
public:
    parent(int number){
        cout<<"Value of the number from parent class is: "<<number<<endl;
    }
};
class child: public parent{
public:
    using parent::parent;//Adding the parent constructor to this scope
    child(): parent(10){
    }
};
class child2: public child{
public:
    using child::child; //Adding the child constructor to this scope
    child2(): child(10){
    }
};
int main()
{
    child2 ob(100);
    return 0;
}
//Output: Value of the number from parent class is: 100
```